# Sorting firebase data by date

Tags: java, android, firebase, sorting

I looked at the related problems on the site and applied them, but my problem continues, I write below in detail

```
"Davalar" : {
"rfsnknKT0QPtuwZiYoVaA9tZt4t2" : {
  "-M6FPIAqsR6H87xqD8CD" : {
    "davaTarihi" : "2/5/2020",
    "davaTuru" : "aaa",
    "esasNo" : "22",
    "kararNo" : "22",
    "key" : "-M6FPIAqsR6H87xqD8CD",
    "notlar" : "",
    "timestamp" : 1588339487723
  },
  "-M6FPsOAMK_5OzucNJlu" : {
    "davaTarihi" : "13/5/2020",
    "davaTuru" : "aaa",
    "esasNo" : "222",
    "kararNo" : "2222",
    "key" : "-M6FPsOAMK_5OzucNJlu",
    "notlar" : "",
    "timestamp" : 1588339640135
  },
  "-M6FPwqLhUn0-phQrN-W" : {
    "davaTarihi" : "8/5/2020",
    "davaTuru" : "aaa",
    "esasNo" : "222",
    "kararNo" : "222",
    "key" : "-M6FPwqLhUn0-phQrN-W",
    "notlar" : "",
    "timestamp" : 1588339658382
  }
}
```

model class

```
public class Davalar {

String davaTarihi, davaTuru, esasNo, kararNo, notlar, key;
Long timestamp;

public Davalar() {

}

public Davalar(String davaTarihi, String davaTuru, String esasNo, String kararNo, String notlar, String key, Long timestamp) {
    this.davaTarihi = davaTarihi;
    this.davaTuru = davaTuru;
    this.esasNo = esasNo;
    this.kararNo = kararNo;
    this.notlar = notlar;
    this.key = key;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public String getDavaTarihi() {
    return davaTarihi;
}

public String getDavaTuru() {
    return davaTuru;
}

public String getEsasNo() {
    return esasNo;
}

public String getKararNo() {
    return kararNo;
}

public String getNotlar() {
    return notlar;
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public Long getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}
```

sorting code

```
databaseReference.child(userId).orderByChild("timestamp").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Davalar davalar = dataSnapshot.getValue(Davalar.class);
            if (davalarList.indexOf(dataSnapshot.getKey()) == -1) {
                davalarList.add(new Davalar(davalar.getDavaTarihi(), davalar.getDavaTuru(),
                        davalar.getEsasNo(), davalar.getKararNo(),
                        davalar.getNotlar(), davalar.getKey(),davalar.getTimestamp()));
            }
```

and output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbnsr.png)
I add timestamp data to the map as long as I add a database

Whatever I did, I could not sort them by date, I am waiting for your help.

Comment: You are not currently sorting your `davalarList` at all. After adding your new item, you need to sort the list (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311557/how-to-sort-objects-in-an-arraylist-with-an-object-parameter)

Comment: but when I pull it from the database to the list, I want to pull it to my list and show it to the user.